# Highcharts - Equal spacing between ticks with provided tickPositions

Tags: highcharts

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        height: 'some height',
    },
    title: {
        text: ""
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [], // data
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            enabled: false
        },
        lineWidth: 1,
        lineColor: 'white',
        tickAmount: 5,
        min: 100000000,
        max: 1000000000000,
        tickPixelInterval: 100,
        tickPositions: [1000000000, 10000000000, 100000000000, 1000000000000]
    },
    yAxis: {
        height: '100%',
        title: {
            enabled: true,
            text: 'Investment'
        },
        tickAmount: 10
    }
})
```

The above code produces something like this [image: The labels on the xAxis are overlapping as there isn't any data for 100 million, 1 billion & 10 billion.]

The labels on the xAxis are overlapping as the range is quite high(Ranging from 100 million to 1 trillion).

On reading highcharts API doc, I found that the method tickPositions overwrites the values in tickPixelInterval & tickInterval. That's why I'm not able to specify custom tickInterval value.

What I want is, to keep equal spacing between each of the mentioned tickPositions. It'll be fine if the bubbles overlap.

Comment: Yes, if you tell the chart you want a tick at `1000000000000`, it will put a tick at `1000000000000` :) For even spacing regardless of value, you should use `categories`, or write your own logic to place the ticks using the `tickPositioner()` function: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.categories | http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositioner

Comment: @jlbriggs Even with tickPositioner(), I'll need some way to set the interval between each tick. This function will just allow me to specify the positions programmatically. What I'm concerned is with not overriding the tickInterval or finding some way to manipulate interval between the ticks with using tickPositioner or tickPositions. Also, I cannot make use of categories in my case